Google form sections and next section
I have prepared a code that reads from a Google Sheet and uses questions. The questions have their own categories. For each category, a separate page is created in the Google Form, and the questions belonging to that category are written down. A first section (or page break) is created where all detected categories are listed, and the user, after selecting one of the categories, is redirected to the page with the questions of the selected category. However, after completing category question section (or page break), the form by default moves to the next section (or page break), and I would like it to redirect to the last section (or page break) instead. How can I prepare a part of the code that manipulates the form area indicated in the picture and redirects to the last page?
Sections

I recommend to provide a [mre] in addition to the desciption of your code. Also please consider taking the [tour] and reading [ask], the info is really helpful.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
